# Mocha Monitor Application Output

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm building a logging module for my web app in `nodejs`. I'd like to be able to test using `mocha` that my module outputs the correct messages to the `terminal`. I have been looking around but haven't found any obvious solutions to check this. I have found

```
process.stdout.on('data', function (){})
```

but haven't been able to get this to work. does anybody have any advice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`process.stdout` is never going to emit `'data'` events because it's not a readable stream.  You can read all about that in the [node stream documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), if you're curious.

As far as I know, the simplest way to hook or capture `process.stdout` or `process.stderr` is to replace `process.stdout.write` with a function that does what you want.  Super hacky, I know, but in a testing scenario you can use before and after hooks to make sure it gets unhooked, so it's more or less harmless.  Since it writes to the underlying stream anyway, it's not the end of the world if you don't unhook it anyway.

```
function captureStream(stream){
  var oldWrite = stream.write;
  var buf = '';
  stream.write = function(chunk, encoding, callback){
    buf += chunk.toString(); // chunk is a String or Buffer
    oldWrite.apply(stream, arguments);
  }

  return {
    unhook: function unhook(){
     stream.write = oldWrite;
    },
    captured: function(){
      return buf;
    }
  };
}
```

You can use it in mocha tests like this:

```
describe('console.log', function(){
  var hook;
  beforeEach(function(){
    hook = captureStream(process.stdout);
  });
  afterEach(function(){
    hook.unhook(); 
  });
  it('prints the argument', function(){
    console.log('hi');
    assert.equal(hook.captured(),'hi\n');
  });
});
```

Here's a caveat: mocha reporters print to the standard output.  They do not, as far as I know, do so while example (`it('...',function(){})`) functions are running, but you may run into trouble if your example functions are asynchronous.  I'll see if I can find more out about this.

Comment: Is this still the case? I'm trying to figure out why I can't hook to `stdout.on('data'` but everything I've found says that it's a readable stream

Answer (score 12):

I've attempted jjm's answer and had problems which I suspect was due to my programs async behaviour.

I found a solution via a cli on github that uses the sinon library.

An example code to test:

```
/* jshint node:true */
module.exports = Test1;

function Test1(options) {
  options = options || {};
}


Test1.prototype.executeSync = function() {
  console.log("ABC");
  console.log("123");
  console.log("CBA");
  console.log("321");
};

Test1.prototype.executeASync = function(time, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("ABC");
    console.log("123");
    console.log("CBA");
    console.log("321");
    callback();
  }, time);
};
```

And the mocha tests:

```
/* jshint node:true */
/* global describe:true, it:true, beforeEach:true, afterEach:true, expect:true */

var assert = require('chai').assert;
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var sinon  = require("sinon");

var Test1 = require("../test");

var test1 = null;

describe("test1", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    sinon.stub(console, "log").returns(void 0);
    sinon.stub(console, "error").returns(void 0);
    test1 = new Test1();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    console.log.restore();
    console.error.restore();
  });

  describe("executeSync", function() {
    it("should output correctly", function() {
      test1.executeSync();

      assert.isTrue(console.log.called, "log should have been called.");
      assert.equal(console.log.callCount, 4);
      assert.isFalse(console.log.calledOnce);
      expect(console.log.getCall(0).args[0]).to.equal("ABC");
      expect(console.log.getCall(1).args[0]).to.equal("123");
      expect(console.log.args[2][0]).to.equal("CBA");
      expect(console.log.args[3][0]).to.equal("321");
    });
  });

  describe("executeASync", function() {
    it("should output correctly", function(done) {
      test1.executeASync(100, function() {
        assert.isTrue(console.log.called, "log should have been called.");
        assert.equal(console.log.callCount, 4);
        assert.isFalse(console.log.calledOnce);
        expect(console.log.getCall(0).args[0]).to.equal("ABC");
        expect(console.log.getCall(1).args[0]).to.equal("123");
        expect(console.log.args[2][0]).to.equal("CBA");
        expect(console.log.args[3][0]).to.equal("321");
        done();
      });

    });
  });
});
```

I'm providing the above as it demonstrates working with async calls, it deals with both console and error output and the method of inspection is of more use.

I should note that I've provided two methods of obtaining what was passed to the console, `console.log.getCall(0).args[0]` and `console.log.args[0][0]`. The first param is the line written to the console. Feel free to use what you think is appropriate.

Comment: This seems like the better answer if only because it leverages the common Sinon stub pattern and is thus possibly more immediately understandable than trying to capture process.stdout or whatever. Might just be me, though...

Comment: test-console is a lightweight library that does what you're talking about @aendrew. See my answer listed here

Answer (score 9):

Two other libraries that help with this are [test-console](https://github.com/jamesshore/test-console) and [intercept-stdout](https://github.com/sfarthin/intercept-stdout) I haven't used intercept-stdout, but here's how you can do it with test-console.

```
var myAsync = require('my-async');
var stdout = require('test-console').stdout;

describe('myAsync', function() {
  it('outputs something', function(done) {
    var inspect = stdout.inspect();

    myAsync().then(function() {
      inspect.restore();
      assert.ok(inspect.output.length > 0);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

**Note:** You must use Mocha's async api. No calling `done()` will swallow mocha's test messaging.

Comment: `test-console` exactly did what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using TypeScript and had an issue with the `write` method of the stream being overloaded in my version of NodeJS.

My adaptation of [@jjm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18543419):

```
export function captureStream(stream: NodeJS.WritableStream) {
  const oldWrite = stream.write
  let buf: string = ""

  class FakeWrite {
    write(chunk, _callback)
    write(chunk, _encoding?, _callback?) {
      buf += chunk.toString()
    }
  }

  stream["write"] = FakeWrite.prototype.write

  return {
    unhook: function unhook() {
      stream.write = oldWrite
    },
    captured: () => {
      return buf
    },
  }
}
```